# Image of linear morphism of affine variety is closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebrically closed field and let $l\colon \mathbb{A}^m_k\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^n_k$ be a one to one morphism of affine variety given by a matrix that maps $x$ to $A[x]$, here $A$ is a matrix. How I can prove that image of $l$ is closed.

I do not want to use the general theorem which says every morphism of projective varieties has closed image.

If you can please help since its some day that I can not prove it.

Comment: Hint: Can you pick a special $A$ where this is obvious? Can you show that you can get to this situation from any $A$?

Comment: This is essentially an exercise in linear algebra: The image of a vector space under a linear map is again a vector space, hence given by finitely many linear equations, i.e. Zariski closed.